# Open morphisms are dominant?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

This seems very elementary but I haven't been able to prove it:

If $f : X \to Y$ is an open map of irreducible topological spaces, then it is dominant (maps generic points to generic points).

It might hold for only schemes, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, suppose it isn't dominant; what can you say about the open set $f(X) \subset Y$?

Comment: i don't see anything besides $f(X) \ne Y$...

Comment: That's not the definition of dominant, though: $f$ not dominant means $f(X)$ is not _dense_ in $Y$. Can that happen, under your hypotheses? (Hint: there's one you didn't use yet...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's be very clear with the definitions.

A map of topological spaces $ f : X \to Y$  is said to be dominant if its image $f(X)\subset Y$ is a dense subset of $Y$, i.e. if $\overline {f(X)}=Y$: nothing less and nothing more.
In particular let's not  mention generic points (which most topological spaces don't have) nor schemes (which have a very rich supplementary structure,  irrelevant in our purely topological context).
An irreducible space is a non-empty space with the property  that all its non-empty open subsets are dense.

To come back to the problem at hand, if $X$ is non-empty and if  $f$ is open, then $f(X)$ is also non-empty and open.
Hence  $f(X)\subset Y$ is dense if $Y$ is irreducible, and thus $f$ is dominant.
Note carefully that irreducibility of $X$ is a totally superfluous hypothesis.

Comment: Wow, i forgot about this characterization of irreducible spaces.  Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, shurik.